# How does external libraries work?

Tags: android, android-library

I am using ZBar library to develop a barcode scanner app. I have added the ZbarLibrary in project properties. I exported the project and installed on my cell. My question is what happens when I add the library in project properties. My cell doesnt contain the library so I suppose the library gets added to my project code only and gets exported with the app. Is it how it happens? If yes then where the library reside in the apk? If no then how is the library referenced when I use it on my phone?

Comment: a/ yes b/ just like any other class in your project.

Comment: Then if I decompile my apk I should be able to see the library?

Comment: if you unzip the apk you'll find a classes.dex file, that contains all the classes from your project and your libraries, yes.